# Results that include space don't get fetched

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

This is the code where I used to get results of different category names. Here, if the category names have space the result won't get displayed while the names without having spaces will get displayed.

### This is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>clients">View All </a></li>
    <?php foreach($clientdropdown as $row){?>
    <li class="<?php if($active_mn== $row->id) echo 'active'; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>client/<?php echo $row->category_name;?>">
            <?php echo $row->category_name;?>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
         <?php }?>

       </ul>
```

I'm a little bit confused with where to use `replace()` to avoid spaces.

i had changed my code please see that

Comment: by "the result won't displayed", do you mean you get redirected to the wrong page or the option doesn't at all show?

Comment: if i had given space in between the category name the result added wont get displayed

Comment: now i had found how to avoid spaces by using replace() method i had used this code  $name = str_replace(' ', '-', $data);

Comment: i want to change it to the url only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at what you are trying to do in your edited code, the problem you had isn't that `$row->category_name` won't fetch.
It is to do with the space in the URL not being probably encoded so the page won't redirect correctly.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
Space is unsafe ASCII character.
URLs cannot contain spaces. 
URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

**`urlencode()`** translates space into +
**`rawurlencode()`** translates parameters into hex code, which is %20 for space

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>clients">View All </a></li>
    <?php foreach($clientdropdown as $row){?>
    <li class="<?php if($active_mn== $row->id) echo 'active'; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>client/<?php echo rawurlencode($row->category_name);?>">
            <?php echo $row->category_name;?>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
         <?php }?>

       </ul>
```

**UPDATE**
codeigniter translates space to underscore when it creates directory with name that contains space, so the correct path to access the directory created using category name "Hello World" should be "Hello_World", for this particular case `str_replace(" ", "_", $row->category_name)` was all there was needed.

Comment: when i give  this my url becomes like this http://localhost/nowaste/client/f+f and showing The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: say for example your category name is "Hello World"
you can't have an address that is /nowaste/client/hello world
localhost/nowaste/client/Hello%20World or localhost/nowaste/client/Hello+World would take you to the directory
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters error message is to do with the  'permitted_uri_chars' setting on your config.php

Comment: my category name is 'public sector' and when i give urlencode() it becomes like this 'public+sector'  but it shows like this The URI you submitted has disallowed characters

Comment: this is my 'permitted_uri_chars'    $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-'; here what changes i should have to made

Comment: To make things simpler for you, try`<?php echo rawurlencode($row->category_name);?>">` instead of `<?php echo urlencode($row->category_name);?>">` used in my example. 
If that gets you to the page that you are good to go. If not you need to either change the config.php file

Comment: @MOHAMMED can you post the `<a href>` code you use? Other than a typo in your code, I can't think of any reason why a space doesn't get translate to %20 using `rawurlencode()`

Comment: sure    `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>client/<?php echo rawurlencode($row->category_name);?>">
                <?php echo $row->category_name;?>
                <span></span>
               </a> `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114404/discussion-between-sml-and-mohammed).